# Communicate action thru directive attributes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm probably missing something here on the way $observe works inside directive. I have to child directive that needs to communicate thru their parent directive:

```
<parent>
  <button>Change text</button>
  <child text="child element"></child>
</parent>

app.directive('button', function() {
  return {
    require: '^parent',
    scope: true,
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, parentCtrl) {
      element.bind('click', function() {
        parentCtrl.changeText();
      });
    },
  };
});

app.directive('parent', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: true,
    controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
      var child = $element.find('child');
      this.changeText = function() {
        child.attr('text', 'new text');
      };
    }
  };
});

app.directive('child', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: true,
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      attrs.$observe('text', function(text) {
        element.html(text);
      });
    }
  };
});
```

That code is only to illustrate an problem I have in the app i'm developing. All directive needs to have a isolated scope, so I cannot communicate with it. I made a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Vwd7o5R9c0RXjaEzHIlh). Feel free to let me know if there's a better way to communicate to the child directive from the parent one.

Thank's a lot, as always!

Comment: why dont use `$emit` and `$on` ?

Answer (score 0):

I didnt understand why the parent and child has to have isolated scope but if you just want to communicate between parent and child you can use  `$emit` and `$on`.

```
app.directive('parent', function($rootScope) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: true,
    controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
      var child = $element.find('child');
      this.changeText = function() {
        child.attr('text', 'new text');
      };

      $rootScope.$emit('FromParent', somedata);
    }
  };
});

app.directive('child', function($rootScope) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: true,
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      attrs.$observe('text', function(text) {
        element.html(text);
      });

     $rootScope.$on('FromParent', function(event, somedata){
        //Do something with the data
     });
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: I know it doesn't make sense in my example to use isolated scope. But in my project, all those directives are independents and reusables. That's why I prefer isolated scope. I'm looping for a way to trigger events insides directives by changing there attributes.

Comment: @leseulsteve you can use the **Mediator Pattern** http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern . Have a central point e.g. a service which is listening for event and emit events back to the directives that should listen for them.